# How to add a script to command list

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am using sage a math library in python. After downloading its package, I usually have to go to the directory where I extracted it and then run the the script using

```
sudo ./sage
```

from terminal. How can I add sage to the list of installed applications, that I will be able to run the script by typing sage command from any directory in terminal?

Comment: Is there a particular reason, why you run a mathematical application with super-user privileges? I doubt that's necessary and you should avoid that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to add that scripts directory to your `PATH` variable. This can become tedious if you download a lot of self-contained executables. My recommendation would be to create a `bin` folder in your home folder and place all your self-contained executable files in there.

Most recent versions of Ubuntu already have their `PATH` setup to read from `$HOME/bin` so it'll work after a restart of the terminal or after you type `source ~/.profile`. Once that's completed you should be able to just enter `sage` in to the terminal.

If you wanted to add another directory, other than `~/bin`, you can open the `.profile` file in your home directory and add the following line to the bottom:

```
PATH="/path/to/folder:$PATH"
```

Replacing `/path/to/folder` with the absolute path to the directory you wish to add. That will prepend the directory of your choice to your `PATH` environment and it'll take effect once you enter `source ~/.profile` (or restart the terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Put the script in your `bin` directory.